# Using the VS Web Test Classes outside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, httpwebrequest, webrequest, webtest

I use HttpWebRequests pretty extensively - I've found that the Visual Studio Web Test classes (i.e. WebTestRequest and WebTestResponse etc) offer a lot of really nice methods that i'd love to start using.

But I can't seem to find a way to use these classes outside of the Visual Studio's testing framework.  Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will,
WebTestRequest and WebTestResponse aren't designed to be used like HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.  They're mostly containers for passing various request and response data into and out of the web/load test engine in Visual Studio or MSTest.

I wrote both of the classes and even I find myself wishing I could use them for other purposes :)  I've definitely had to reinvent similar querystring parameter parsing logic for other projects since then.

Josh

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  There are some really nice parts about these classes (easy interface, stats, ParseDependantRequests) that I was really hoping I wouldn't have to re-write.  

Did I read correctly, you "wrote the classes"? Do you work in Building 42?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the classes, but I worked in the "Visual Studio - North Carolina" office in Durham, NC.  I left Microsoft a little more than two years ago, though.